# How to fill in a gap between two objects?

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, edit-mode

How do you fill in a gap between two objects? I got a gap between the car body and the black window trim panel. I keep getting errors that says "No Faces Filled". I just want to cover the edges and needs to be a separate object.

[image: Gap]

Comment: hello, I think your question is not clear, you want to fill a gap between what objects and what do you mean by filling a gap? You can't create any faces between 2 different objects, you need first to join them if this is what you mean

Comment: @moonboots: i think he wants to fill the gap between the black thing around the window and the red chassis.

Comment: As moonboots said, you can't fill between two objects.
I would suggest to join both objects (ctrl J) and then perform that action of joining.
you can separate those objects after doing it.

Comment: try bridge edge loops after joining the two objects

Comment: You can duplicate the border edge loop of one of the objects, separate it, then join to the other, then fill that gap.